# laravel custom primary key attributes

Tags: database, laravel

I have made a custom primary key in Laravel. On my model

```
protected $primaryKey = ['profileId'];

public $incrementing = false;

Migration = $table->integer('profileId')->unsigned();

$table->primary('profileId');
```

Is there use of making a custom primary key `unsigned()`. ?

Comment: Can you explain better your question?

Comment: @Troyer . in laravel migration how to set a custom primary key where primary key is profileId

Comment: And you want it `unsigned` and auto-incrementing correct?

Answer (score 1):

you use `unsigned()` to have only positive values,  since `AUTO_INCREMENT` starts at zero by default and increments in the positive direction, it's more convenient to utilize the positive values than the negative value.On your mogration file add:

```
$table->primary('profileId')->unsigned();
```

In case you want a string as primary key then;

```
$table->string('column', 30)->primary();
```

and

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: in case primary key is string. then how to declare.?

Comment: $table->string('column', 30)->primary();   and public $incrementing = false;

Answer (score 0):

In your migration when you are creating the table you can indicate the primary key with `primary()`:

```
Schema::create('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->primary('profileId');  
});
```

If your primary key is a string you need to add to your model:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: so no need to make unsigned() ?    and if data type of primary key is string or some other data type.?

Comment: Unsigned values means that the value will not have `+` or `-`signs, you have a lot of information.  Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553707/what-does-signed-and-unsigned-values-mean

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserVerification extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name'; // or null

public $incrementing = false;
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged; would you mind explaining what you're doing so future readers can more easily understand?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes), You can try below code if your primary key is a string:

```
$table->tinyInteger('profileId');
$table->primary('profileId');
```

And if you want it as auto increment you have to do something like this

```
$table->tinyInteger('profileId')->unsigned()->autoIncrement()‌​;
```